# Releasing iVar IBOutlet vs Property IBOutlet

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management, memory-leaks

Can anyone verify my dealloc method is correct? Since my titleLabel and checkImageView are retained I am releasing them in dealloc. However, I am not releasing mainImageView, doneButton, and noteLabel, because they are not retained or alloced during the implementation.

```
@interface CheckMarkController : UIViewController  <UIAlertViewDelegate> {
IBOutlet UIImageView *mainImageView;
IBOutlet UIButton *doneButton;
IBOutlet UILabel *noteLabel;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *checkImageView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Event *event;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Workout *workout;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

@end

- (void)dealloc {
//props
[titleLabel release];
[checkImageView release];
[event release];
[workout release];
[managedObjectContext release];

[super dealloc];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you connect these three items via Interface Builder you DO need to release them. Outlets are retained by default. KVC (Key Value Coding) is used to set outlets. This means that `loadFromNib` will call `setValue:withKey` for each outlet you have set. This uses the `@property` and it's setter method, but if none are set (as is your case) it retains the object by default.

Comment: I see, is it normal for these leaks to not show up in Instruments?

Comment: Edited to give more detail. In my experience Instruments has issues with KVC. Someone else might have better insight though.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I have corrected the code and added this to my list of "gotchas"